# XML file download in Compact framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact

Basically, Here is the scenario.I created  mobile optimised ASP.NET(3.5 framework) apllication and I added a link to download xml file on to Motorola GUN  which runs on comapct framework 5.0 operation system.

File download logic works fine on desktop/laptop but on windows CE device Instead of downloading the file.It is opening xml file in IE browser.

I need experties help here :)

Answer (score 0):

The device is going to handle files that it is designed for.

You could try sending your file as an octet stream.

Here is something similar I did a while back, but I'm not certain if it works on Mobile devices:

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameOnly)) {
      string filename = Server.MapPath(nameOnly);
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) {
        try {
          Response.Buffer = false;
          Response.Clear(); // clear the buffer
          Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
          if (-1 < filename.IndexOf(".avi")) {
            Response.ContentType = "video/x-msvideo";
          } else if (-1 < filename.IndexOf(".pdf")) {
            Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
          } else if (-1 < filename.IndexOf(".rar")) {
            Response.ContentType = "Application/x-rar-compressed";
          } else {
            Response.ContentType = "Application/octet-stream";
          }
          FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);
          Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nameOnly);
          Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
          Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        } catch (Exception err) {
          outputLine = err.Message;
        } finally {
          Response.Flush();
        }
      } else {
        outputLine = string.Format("Server was unable to locate file \"{0}\".", nameOnly);
      }
    }
```

Comment: @jp2code- Thanks for the help.Actually,I tried this approach but the result is same.It works well in desktop but not in Windows CE.